# предзагрузка изображений через JS для последующего использования на Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.В чем проблема?
` let imgArr = [];

```
  function preloadImages(sources) {
   let k = 0
  for (let source of sources) {
   let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = source.src;
  img.value = source.value;
imgArr.push(img);
 };
k++;
}

let sources = [
{ src: 'images/3-3/image_part_001.jpg', value: 0 },
{ src: 'images/3-3/image_part_002.jpg', value: 1 },
{ src: 'images/3-3/image_part_003.jpg', value: 2 },
{ src: 'images/3-3/image_part_004.jpg', value: 3 },
{ src: 'images/3-3/image_part_005.jpg', value: 4 },
{ src: 'images/3-3/image_part_006.jpg', value: 5 },
{ src: 'images/3-3/image_part_007.jpg', value: 6 },
{ src: 'images/3-3/image_part_008.jpg', value: 7 },
{ src: 'images/3-3/image_part_009.jpg', value: 8 },
 ];

preloadImages(sources);`
```

далее идет функция отрисовки :

```
  `function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawPlayingField();
  addInactiveImages();
  addActiveImages();
  drawScoreField()
  }

  draw();


function addInactiveImages() {  
let k = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < rightField.length; i++) {
let a = rightField[i];
if (!a.isActive) {
  ctx.drawImage(imgArr[k], a.x, a.y, a.s, a.s);
  a.value = imgArr[k].value;
}
k++;
}
}

function addActiveImages() {
let k = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < rightField.length; i++) {
let a = rightField[i];
if (a.isActive) {
  ctx.drawImage(imgArr[k], a.x, a.y, a.s, a.s);
  a.value = imgArr[k].value;
}
k++;
}
}`
```

она отрисовывает все, кроме картинок.
на элементе canvas висят слушатели событий, в том числе и mouse move, который вызывает функцию перерисовки draw. при первом mouse move картинки появляется. но не сразу при загрузке страницы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так тоже работает:

```
function preloadImages(sources, callback) {

    let counter = 0;

    function onLoad() {
        counter++;
        if (counter == sources.length) callback();
    }

    let k = 0
    for (let source of sources) {
        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.onload = img.onerror = onLoad;
        img.src = source.src;
        img.value = source.value;
        imgArr.push(img);
    }
    k++;
}

let sources = [
    { src: 'images/3-3/image_part_001.jpg', value: 0 },
    { src: 'images/3-3/image_part_002.jpg', value: 1 },
    { src: 'images/3-3/image_part_003.jpg', value: 2 },
    { src: 'images/3-3/image_part_004.jpg', value: 3 },
    { src: 'images/3-3/image_part_005.jpg', value: 4 },
    { src: 'images/3-3/image_part_006.jpg', value: 5 },
    { src: 'images/3-3/image_part_007.jpg', value: 6 },
    { src: 'images/3-3/image_part_008.jpg', value: 7 },
    { src: 'images/3-3/image_part_009.jpg', value: 8 },
];

function testLoaded() {
    let widthSum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = sources[i];
    }
    draw();
}

preloadImages(sources, testLoaded);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 5):

Когда вы добавляете на страницу тег img, прямо в этот же момент рисовать их на canvas не имеет смысла, так как они еще не загрузились и даже не посылали запрос серверу чтобы найти картинку, которая уже закешировалась в браузере.

Необходимо дожидаться события `load`, после него можно отрисовывать картинки на `canvas`.

Это бы могло выглядеть так:

```
async function loadAndDraw(images){
  let loaded = await Promise.all(images.map(source => 
     new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       let img = document.createElement("img");
       Object.assign(img, source);
       img.onload = ()=> resolve(img);
       img.onerror = (event)=> reject(event);
    })
  ));
  // ... рисование на canvas ...
}
```